# Are client component children also client comoonents in next 13 app router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js13, app-router

Are children of a client component in nextjs 13 app router also app components even if they don't have the 'use client' directive?

Was learning using the nextjs 13 app router in a project and trying to understand how client and server components work

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.